# [HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A mi parecer todo va Ok, pero cuando hace la sentencia me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/APP2/include/crud_usuario.php:119
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/APP2/include/crud_usuario.php(119):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/APP2/include/administrar_usuario.php(42):
>   CrudUsuario->actualizar(Object(Usuario)) #2 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/APP2/include/crud_usuario.php on
>   line 119

```
public function actualizar($usuario){
    $db = BaseDatos::conectar();
    $actualizar = $db->prepare('UPDATE Usuario SET usuario=:usuario,contrasena=:contrasena,nombre=:nombre,apellido=:apellido,dni=:dni,email=:email,telefono=:telefono,direccion=:direccion,cod_postal=:cod_postal,fecha_nac=:fecha_nac,curso=:cruso,foto=:foto,estado=:estado,tipo=:tipo WHERE id_usuario=:id_usuario');

    $actualizar->bindValue(':id_usuario', NULL);
    $actualizar->bindValue(':nombre',$usuario->getNombre());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':apellido',$usuario->getApellido());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':dni',$usuario->getDni());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':usuario',$usuario->getUsuario());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':contrasena',$usuario->getContrasena());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':email',$usuario->getEmail());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':telefono',$usuario->getTel());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':direccion',$usuario->getDireccion());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':cod_postal',$usuario->getCodPostal());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':fecha_nac',$usuario->getFechaNac());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':curso',$usuario->getCurso());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':foto',$usuario->getFoto());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':estado',$usuario->getEstado());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':tipo',$usuario->getTipo());

    $actualizar->execute();
}
```

Comment: ¿Te has fijado que estás actualizando únicamente el `id_usuario` que vale `NULL`? Te recomiendo ENCARECIDAMENTE que tabules el SQL como en la última respuesta que te di. Mejorará mucho la depuración.

Comment: Hola gracias por la recomendación así lo tengo y es más ágil y comprensible gracias. He borrado     $actualizar->bindValue(':id_usuario', NULL); pero me sigue saliendo el error. Siento mi falta de comprensión pues estoy aprendiendo y estos errores entiendo que son cosas básicas. Gracias

Comment: Mira mi respuesta (la estaba redactando cuando escribí el comentario). Tu problema está en que no coinciden el nombre que has dado a una variable dentro del SQL y fuera de éste. Si tabulas correctamente el código como te pongo en mi respuesta podrás depurar estas cosas de manera más sencilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es que estás usando en el SQL un marcador (placeholder) con nombre `:cruso` (`curso=:cruso`) pero luego le asignas valor al marcador `:curso` en el `bindValue`.

Al ejecutar la consulta PDO te genera una excepción porque MySQL no encuentra valores para todos los marcadores, por eso te aparece ese mensaje de error:

> Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

En castellano:

> Número de parámetros inválido: el parámetro no fue definido

Lo ideal sería que `bindValue` fuera quien detectara las incoherencias, pero por desgracia no es así y de ahí que éste sea un error muy común.

He arreglado tu código para que en el SQL se muestre el nombre correcto:

```
public function actualizar($usuario) {
    $db = BaseDatos::conectar();
    $actualizar = $db->prepare('
      UPDATE Usuario
      SET
        usuario = :usuario,
        contrasena = :contrasena,
        nombre = :nombre,
        apellido = :apellido,
        dni = :dni,
        email = :email,
        telefono = :telefono,
        direccion = :direccion,
        cod_postal = :cod_postal,
        fecha_nac = :fecha_nac,
        curso = :curso,
        foto = :foto,
        estado = :estado,
        tipo = :tipo
      WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario
    ');

    $actualizar->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario->getUsuario());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':contrasena', $usuario->getContrasena());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':nombre', $usuario->getNombre());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':apellido', $usuario->getApellido());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':dni', $usuario->getDni());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':email', $usuario->getEmail());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':telefono', $usuario->getTel());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':direccion', $usuario->getDireccion());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':cod_postal', $usuario->getCodPostal());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':fecha_nac', $usuario->getFechaNac());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':curso', $usuario->getCurso());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':foto',$usuario->getFoto());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':estado',$usuario->getEstado());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':tipo',$usuario->getTipo());
    $actualizar->bindValue(':id_usuario', $usuario->getIdUsuario());

    $actualizar->execute();
}
```

Comment: Ahora mismo no me genera ningún error gracias, no me actualiza los datos pero voy a tratar de ver que es, muchas gracias!

Comment: Según entiendo el error se debe a un error tipográfico, por lo que no deberías haber respondido sino marcado la pregunta.

Comment: No te actualiza los datos porque no estás poniendo un valor en `:id_usuario` que exista en la tabla. Si usas `$usuario->getIdUsuario()` te funcionará.

Comment: @sergibarca, ¿existe un usuario con `id` igual a `NULL`? ¿No será este el motivo?

Comment: @Marcos, no es un error tipográfico en el código, si no un error que se provoca al asignar a una variable incorrecta ya que el contenido de una cadena de texto no coincide y, por lo tanto, se queda sin asignar la variable necesaria. Un error tipográfico sería no poner un punto y coma, no llamar a una función por su nombre, etc...

Comment: No, no existe el usuario con id NULL, de ahi vendrá el problema...

Comment: @OscarGarcia, es un error tipográfico desde el momento en que ha escrito mal el nombre de la variable y siendo este el motivo del error.

Comment: @sergibarca, esa misma pregunta te la hice yo en tu pregunta y te he respondido en estos comentarios. Editaré mi pregunta para incluir ese cambio.

Comment: Me ayudáis un montón gracias, voy a tratar de que me haga eso!

Comment: No es el nombre de una variable, es una cadena de texto (voy a llamarlo "placeholder"). @Marcos, el nombre del "placeholder" no es lo que provoca el error, por lo que ningún analizador léxico te encontraría ese error. Es un error lógico. El error se provoca por dejar de asignar el valor a un "placeholder" de SQL. Viene bien que quede registrado el problema y su solución para que **aquellas personas que sufran el mismo mensaje de error conozcan el origen del problema**.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, el "_analizador léxico_" es el `motor de SQL` y justamente es el que disapra el error, sino el OP no habrá puesto es su pregunta el error que recibe. `SQL` el que detecta el error de sintaxis, al momento de encontrar `curso=:cruso` y no tener comillas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, es decir que la respuesta va a ser "esta mal escrita el nombre de la variable", cierto?

Comment: No, la respuesta es que no se corresponden todos los marcadores con sus asignaciones de variable, por eso al ejecutar la consulta se queja de que no coinciden.

Comment: A mí me hace este error, y no es por eso. He repasado mi código de a A a la Z; la variable llega correctamente; el placeholder es correcto; y aún así, me da *este mismo error!* y lo peor es que antes funcionaba, y no le he hecho cambios!  Es exasperante!

Comment: ¿Podemos abrir una sala de chat para comprobarlo mañana por la mañana? Sin ver el SQL ni el código PHP no puedo ayudarte.